# YII2 how to rewrite url to receive the params

Tags: php, yii2

I have a request url like this:
`http://www.test.com/parse/demo.apk`

How can I rewrite this url so then controller ParaseController, actionIndex could receive the "demo.apk" as a param?

Comment: Have you checked custom URL or routing rules in Yii? Following may guide you
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/62952-how-create-custom-url-in-yii2/

Comment: i mean if it can be edited in the web.php, use urlmanage?how to write it?

Answer (score 0):

[Add the rule](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#using-pretty-urls) to the `$rules` array of the UrlManager

```
'parse/<package:[a-z\.]+>' => 'parse/index'
```

Now the `actionIndex($package)` becomes the get parameter of the package name `$package`.

[Read more about Url creation in the Docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html)

Comment: also 404 not found，：（

Comment: If you want to get help from people you have to provide more informations (in a well formatted way): what is the namespace of the controller? can you resolve the route with url routing disabled `r=parse/index&package=demo.apk` (not sure this is your controller logic). What says the [gyii2 debug log](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-debug)? Configuration files? etc.